# Porting a codec from pc environment to DSP environment

Tags: android, optimization, codec

I know about basic things like floating point ops might not be supported,there should be less mallocs and asm code etc .But I can't find an exact answer that if I have framework for a video codec in c and I want to run the same on DSP. What kind of changes are needed.

Comment: If you want any real efficiency, you need to understand the algorithm enough to be able to reshuffle it into operations the particular dsp hardware is good at.  But if you just want to live with what a compiler gives you, not much beyond getting the data in and out.

Comment: Thanks Chris yup will need to understand and optimize the algorithms :)